# Dependence of electrostatic force on the surrounding medium

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves, charge, vector-fields

Two unlike point charges held at a fixed distance from each other. The force between them is measured. Then a brass rod is placed exactly in the midpoint of the line joining the 2 charges. Will the new attractive force between the two charges be greater or lesser than the value obtained first?

On placing the brass rod there will be a rearrangement of charges inside the rod due to which the electric field inside the brass rod must become zero. But the energy required for this must be supplied the electric field, right? So, the energy available for the electric field to be spent on exerting a force on the charges decreases. This implies that the force must decrease. But is there any way for the force to increase? Is there anything else going on which somewhat overcompensates this decrease in force?